# What is the meaning of minHessian (Surffeaturedetector)

Tags: c++, opencv

What does `minhessian` exactly mean in the following case

```
int minHessian = 50;

SurfFeatureDetector  detector(minHessian);
```

I have read that it is a threshold...but what does it mean?...That only 50 keypoints are detected?

Answer (score 30):

To decide if a pixel in an image is a SURF keypoint, an approximation of the Hessian matrix is built with the partial derivatives of the image intensities within a patch around the pixel. The determinant of this matrix is called Hessian and tells you how robust that pixel is as a blob center.

The `minHessian` is a threshold to decide from which value you are willing to accept keypoints. In practice, the higher the `minHessian`, the fewer keypoints you will obtain, but you expect them to be more repetitive (w.r.t. image transformations), and then, more useful. On the other hand, the lower the `minHessian`, the more keypoints you get, but they may be more noisy.

In usual images, a value between 400 and 800 works well.

Note that `SurfFeatureDetector` does not provide a way to select just a fixed number of keypoints. To do so, you have to set a low minHessian, sort the resulting keypoints by its Hessian value and then remove the least persistent ones.

Comment: Just a quick note on this, for people who need use this. You can get the hessian values of each keypoint in 'vector<KeyPoint> keypoints' with:  for (int i=0; i<keypoints.size() ; i++) keypoints.at(i).response

Comment: @ChronoTrigger: "sort the resulting keypoints by its Hessian value" which value? Can you explain the meaning of the values? I see size, angle, response, octave and class_id. What does the values represent? E.g. all except size seems weird.

Comment: @JohnBoe `response` is the Hessian value in this case. In general, `response` is some score that depends on the specific feature detection algorithm.