# OpenCV SURFDetector Range of minHessian

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm using the OpenCV SURFDetector to search for keypoints in an image. In my program I want to give the user the opportunity to set the value of the minHessian with a trackbar, but this means that I would have to know the range of the hessian-values.

I know that the higher I set this threshold the less keypoints I get and vice versa.

Is there a way to calculate a range of the hessian values so I can set 0 (which would be a very high minHessian threshold) on my trackbar to “no keypoints” and 100 (which is probably minHessian=1 or 0) for “all possible keypoints”?

I’ve already taken a look at this question, but this doesn’t help me out here:
[Whats the meaning of minHessian (Surffeaturedetector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613723/whats-the-meaning-of-minhessian-surffeaturedetector)

**Edit:** I've found a way for my application that works, but I'm not happy with this solution. This is what I am doing now: I constantly raise my minHessian and check if I still find keypoints, but this variant is neither fast nor really exact because I have to take bigger steps (in my case i+=100) to get results faster. I'm pretty sure there is  another solution. What about binary search or something similar? Is it really not possible to calculate the maxHessian value?

Here's my code:

C#-side:

```
private int getMaxHessianValue()
{
   int maxHessian = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i+=100)
   {
       int numberOfKeypoints = GetNumberOfKeypoints(pathToImage, i);

       if (numberOfKeypoints == 0) // no keypoints found? -> maxHessian
       {
            maxHessian = i;
            break;
       }
   }
   return maxHessian;
}
```

C++-side:

```
int GetNumberOfKeypoints(char* path, int minHessian)
{
    /// Load image
    Mat templ;
    templ = imread( path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );


    // Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector.detect( templ, keypoints );

        // return number of keypoints
    return keypoints.size(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question regarding an upper bound on the [determinant of the] Hessian, and I haven't found an answer from the theoretical point of view.

However, for your particular purpose, I would recommend you to go to the source code of the SURF detector, in particular, find the part for SURFFindInvoker::findMaximaInLayer and you will see that keypoint detections are accepted/rejected through this conditional: if( val0 > hessianThreshold ). So, i think you could insert a couple of lines of code just before the IF statement in order to store the maximum of val0 and this will tell you the maximum of the Hessian for that particular image. Notice that you must make sure that the maximum is stored across all layers and octaves, otherwise you'll be finding a local maximum only.

Of course you may think of something much more elegant, but basically that's where you'll find the maximum directly. What you have implemented is an indirect way of finding out the value.

Hope this is helpful, Lood Guck!